# Fixing a JOptionsPane Loop

Tags: java

I am attempting to fix a loop in my program and having some serious problems. To be more exact I am trying to add a loop. The program is very complex so I'll try to explain as best as I can. Let me start with the problem area:

```
public static void displayGUI(){//Method to display the GUI. 


//Creates a JOptionPane for the first GUI featuring 7 buttons and 2 lists..
int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, getPanel(),"Return Builder", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, 
        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, new String[]{"Confirm","Create Return"}, "default");

if(result == 1){//If the user selects clicks the "Create Return" button..

    initialScreenDecisions="NONE";//The user did not choose to add any entry details to the output list.
    MainWriter.finishedCounter=true;//The boolean counter to trigger that the return is finished goes to true.
    while(MainWriter.entryDetails.size()>0){//Removes all entry details from the input list.
        MainWriter.entryDetails.remove(0);
    }

    while(output.size()>0){//Removes all entry details from the output list..
        output.remove(0);
    }

}

}
```

The class above creates a GUI with two lists where the contents can be transferred back and forwards using arrow buttons and also two standard JOptionPane buttons that are titled "Confirm" and "Create Return". When the user clicks the "Create Return" method then the program basically ends and a file is generated for them. If they do not click "Create Return" the program continues as usual and other dialog's appear. The problem I'm having is that I have been asked to make it so that the "Create Return" button doesn't work unless they have reached a certain point in the program. (This program makes several loops through the above method, depending on the input file since it's a buffered reader/writer.)

So what I really need is to simply make it where depending on a variable if they select result 1 an error message will appear and the program will not advance. The problem is that even if I add a condition into the program at this stage with the error message the program will still advance. The "Cancel" button on a JOptionsPane will close that pane and my program will continue as usual.

How can I make that option display a message but go no further in the program? Treat it like a JButton with an active listener instead of a JOptionsPane button.

The other button ("Confirm") works fine as a JOptionsButton because it advances the program just as it's supposed to. In addition the "Create Return" button works fine in the cases where the variable check is met. It changes some variables and the program continues as usual. I just need this one instance where the button won't advance the program forwards and the user can choose another button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing an array of Strings to your `showOptionDialog()`, you can pass an array of buttons, each with their own ActionListener:

```
final JButton button = new JButton("Something");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent ae) {
        // do something
    }
});

final Object[] options = new Object[] { button };

int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, getPanel(),"Return Builder", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, "default");
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. That solved my problem perfectly. I then used "JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();" to close the window in the situation where the Create Return button is supposed to work. If you know of a better way to close the window please let me know!